# SQL Count total of addresses

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Here is my data

```
Vehicle    | Street       | Number | Postcode
Car          Fakestreet      3       0010NK
Motorbike    Fakestreet      3       0010NK
Car          Fakestreet      4       0010NK
Car          Fakestreet      1       0010NK
Companycar   Fakestreet      1       0010NK
```

I want to count unique adresses per postcode so this is want I want to see:

```
Postcode | Total_adresses
0010NK   | 3
```

I thought this must be a simple query so I have this:

```
SELECT Postcode, COUNT(*) AS total_adresses
FROM my_database
WHERE Postcode = '0010NK'
GROUP BY Postcode, Street, Number
```

But I get this result:

```
Postcode | total_adresses
0010NK   | 2
0010NK   | 2
0010NK   | 1
```

I can't get my head around why it doesn't give me the desired result. Any ideas why?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using! (The accepted answer is product specific.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just aggregate by the one column:

```
SELECT Postcode, COUNT(*) AS total_adresses
FROM my_database
WHERE Postcode = '0010NK'
GROUP BY Postcode;
```

The combination of keys in the `GROUP BY` defines each *row* in the aggregated result set.  You want only one row per `Postcode`, so that is the only key you should have in the `GROUP BY`.

EDIT:

To count the number of distinct addresses, use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.  Here is one way:

```
SELECT Postcode, COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(STREET, ' ', NUMBER, ' ', POSTALCODE) AS total_adresses
FROM my_database
WHERE Postcode = '0010NK'
GROUP BY Postcode;
```

Some databases support:

```
SELECT Postcode, COUNT(DISTINCT STREET, NUMBER, POSTALCODE) AS total_adresses
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Doing that I get a total of 5 adresses but I want 3 because there are three unique adressess for that postcode.

Answer (score 1):

Have a derived table to return the unique addresses. Then GROUP BY its result:

```
select Postcode, count(*)
from
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Street, Number, Postcode
    FROM my_database
) dt
group by Postcode
```